# Using dashed webservice methods names in .Net

Tags: .net, web-services, proxy-classes, wsdl.exe

I'm trying to use a CGI web service. The Web Service method names contain dashes and wsdl.exe removes them in the generated proxy class.

Trying to use the proxy class web service I'm getting an error: "Method 'q1:methodname' not implemented: method name or namespace not recognized"

Then I've tried to change MedhodName parameters (with original dashed method name) in Invoke and BeginInvoke functions in the proxy class. But this time I'm  getting an error "method-name Web Service method name is not valid."

Is there a way to solve this problem. The CGI web service is another company's application and I'm not able to change it.

Comment: Microsoft has stated that ASMX web services are a "legacy technology". You should move to WCF ASAP. While you're at it, you may find that it does not have this problem.

Comment: Also, I suggest you update the web reference, do a build, then post the complete build error or exception here. If it's an exception, then catch it and post the result of ex.ToString(). This problem may have nothing to do with dashes in the operation name.